# Android MediaPlayer Stops Song after 15 Seconds of Playing

Tags: android, kotlin, audio-player

I'm trying to run an application that plays a song throughout the app. I'm using Android MediaPlayer and my code is as follows:

```
        var player = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, R.raw.quiz_music)
        if (!player.isPlaying())
        {
            player.start()
            player.setLooping(true)
        }
```

So the quiz_music.mp3 file is 11 minutes long and I want the media player to play the file and repeat when the song finishes. However, the app plays the song for 15 seconds and stops completely without looping. Is there anything I can do to let the MediaPlayer play the full mp3 file?